# How can I make the product of this VBA snippet dynamically update the table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a master sheet with all of my data. I respectfully "stole" the following code to copy all rows that contained a certain text string in the second column to another sheet.

```
For Each r In Src.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
 If r.Value = "1. Early Season Visits" Then
 If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set CopyRange = r.EntireRow
    Else
            Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, r.EntireRow)
    End If
 End If
Next r
If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
CopyRange.Copy Dst.Range("A1")
End If
End Sub
```

The formatting above got messed up, but you should get the idea. This worked as advertised after I made adjustments for my particular case. It even tried to carry over the conditional formatting rules - though I did have to make minor adjustments to all of those to get it right because excel did some relative reference nonsense.

The problems with the above are:

1. The results are static. If I make a change in the Master Sheet, they are not updated in the sheet where this code runs. There's got to a better/different way to do this that updates across all sheets.
2. I expect that if I update manually by running the code again it will mess up the conditional formatting again - which isn't an insignificant fix.

So, is there a better way to do what I'm looking to accomplish? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert formulas in each cell instead of values

```
For Each r In Src.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
  If r.Value <> "9999999**" Then
      Dst.Range("A" & r.row).Formula = "=Sheet6!A" & r.row
      Dst.Range("B" & r.row).Formula = "=Sheet6!B" & r.row
  ...and so on...

  End If
Next r
```

IN response to you question, I will assume you know where to put the code and the issue is what it does.

`Dst.Range("A" & r.row).Formula = "=Sheet6!A" & r.row`

As r loops through all the cells in Sheet6, column A, it will take the row of the current r (`r.row`) and insert the formula in the corresponding cell of Sheet7. So if r is the first cell in Sheet6 (A1) then in cell A1 of Sheet7 will have the following formula inserted in it: `=Sheet6!A1` and Sheet B1 will have `=Sheet6!B1` ...and so on...

It is sometimes useful to try and insert the formulas by hand at first to get a better idea of what they should be before coding them in your macro

Comment: Let me preface this by saying thank you for your answer, but I'm not at a level to know what to do with this?